# Regex pattern for searches with include and exclude

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a Regex pattern for searches that should allow optional '+' sign to include in the search and '-' sign to exclude from the search. For example: *+apple orange -peach* should search for apples and oranges and not for peaches. Also the pattern should allow for phrases in double quotes mixed with single words, for example: *"red apple" -"black grape" +orange* - you get the idea, same as most of the internet searches.
So I am running 2 regular expressions, first to pick all the negatives, which is simple because '-' is required:

```
(?<=[\-]"?)((?<=")(?<exclude>[^"]+)|(?<exclude>[^\s,\+\-"]+))
```

And second to pick positives, and it is a little more complex because '+' is optional:

```
((?<=[\+\s]")(?<include>[^\s"\+\-][^"]+))|(?<include>(?<![\-\w]"?)([\w][^,\s\-\+]+))(?<!")
```

Positive search is where I am having a problem, it works fine when I run it in RegexBuddy but when I try in .Net the pattern picks up second word from negative criteria, for example in -"black grape" it picks up word 'grape' even though it ends with double quote.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is really not a job for regex. A simple string search would do the job and simplify it all.

Comment: I have to agree here. You want to have everything from the string anyway, just go for a very, very simple state based parser. You save yourself a headache and it's probably even a lot faster.

Comment: I'm with Max on this one, regex are cool, but they have their place. A simple string parser or crawl would be much easier.

Comment: actually I played with it a little and was able to fix it:
((?<=[\+\s]")(?<include>[^\s\"\+\-][^"]+))(?=\")|(?<![\-\w"])(?<include>[\w][^,\s\-\+"]+)(?![\w"])
This one works in .Net

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
[\+-]?(\w+|"[\w\s]+")
```

Starts with a + or -, optional, then matches any word or any word with spaces inside quotes.
Another advice: to experiment with regular expressions, download a tool like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) or [The Regulator](http://osherove.com/tools).

Here is an example using named groups, so you separate sign and value directly with the regex:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string test = "\"red apple\" -\"black grape\" +orange";
    Regex r = new Regex( "(?<sign>[\\+-]?)((?<value>\\w+)|\"(?<value>[\\w\\s]+)\")",RegexOptions.Compiled);

    foreach (Match m in r.Matches(test)) {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["sign"]);
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["value"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple, but there is a reason why I have look-ahead and look-behind in my pattern, so that I do not have to pick up + - and double quotes in my result. I was able to fix my positive search pattern:
((?<=[\+\s]")(?<include>[^\s\"\+\-][^"]+))(?=\")|(?<![\-\w"])(?<include>[\w][^,\s\-\+"]+)(?![\w"])